# Async api call to get PDF returns a blank PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I can pull the populated pdf in Postman fine, but my code only shows a blank pdf:

```
async function getWeeklyReport(queryString) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      url: 'https://reports.myApi.com/ReportCenter/Bookings',
      qs: queryString,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Accept': 'application/pdf',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(process.env.apiEmail + ':' + process.env.apiPassword, 'utf8').toString('base64')
      }
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
          resolve(body);
        } else if (response.statusCode === 409) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(getWeeklyReport(queryString));
          }, response.headers['Retry-After'] * 1000);
        } else {
          reject(response);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And here's where I write it:

```
async function saveCSVLocally(path, obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(path, obj, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
        console.log(err);
      } else{
        console.log('File saved locally');
      }
    });
  })
}
```

I've tried calling a couple ways, neither work:

```
const report = await getWeeklyReport(queryString);
//saveFileLocally(localPath, report);//.then(emailSender.sendNewEmail());
//fs.writeFileSync("test.pdf", report,'binary');
```

So how can I pull this pdf correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're calling the `resolve()` and `reject()` functions of the promise to complete the promise:

```
function saveCSVLocally(path, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(path, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
        reject(err);
     } else {
        console.log('File saved locally');
        resolve();
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Also: Remember, that `fs.writeFile()`'s second parameter is a string (Not an object), although technically it can take a buffer which happens to be one. I'd personally use the variable `data` to avoid confusion.

Comment: But what about actually saving the pdf? Its still blank

Comment: @no_parachute44 `console.log(data)`, is it a string?

Comment: The saved file is a bunch of this "efbf bdef bfbd 11e0 a1b1 1aef bfbd 0000".